# android xml parser issue

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse below xml data but i did not get the case content using dom parser
Please let me know how can i do this. thanks in advance.
xml data

```
<result>
<options id="1">
<question>who will win</question>
<case text="A" total="23" vote="17" percent="73.91"/>
<case text="B" total="23" vote="3" percent="13.04"/>
<case text="c" total="23" vote="1" percent="4.35"/>
<case text="d" total="23" vote="2" percent="8.7"/>
</options>
</result>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see below SO link of my answer for XML Parsing using DOM Parser.

[DOM Parsing Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12313488/reading-xml-response-in-android/12313676#12313676)

Comment: I have used below code for the same but i did not get the case content

Comment: @user853341 Post your Full Code.